# Chef provisioning resource - Run specific version of cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, provisioning, cookbook

I have a basic machine resource:

```
machine 'admin' do
  recipe 'my_custom_cookbook::super_secret_recipe'
  ohai_hints 'ec2' => '{}'
  action :converge
  converge true
end
```

How can I run a specific version (let's say 0.0.5) of `my_custom_cookbook::super_secret_recipe` against this `machine` resource?

It seems that just adding

```
depends 'my_custom_cookbook', '0.0.5'
```

to the metadata file doesn't work. It always pick the latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provisioning cookbook has no direct relationship to the node it creates so that's why adding that depends wouldn't help. There are three ways to control what version of a cookbook gets used:

1. Use the new Policyfile system. I don't think `cheffish`/`chef-provisioning` have direct support for setting policy name/group yet but you could use the `raw_json` property probably.
2. Use an environment. You can set this via the `chef_environment` property on the `machine` resource. Check the Chef docs for more detailed info on using environments.
3. Set it in the run list, `recipe 'my_custom_cookbook::super_secret_recipe@0.0.5'`. This is a rarely-used feature of Chef and so might not be supported in all places/tools.

Comment: Thanks, we decided to use option 3 as a temporary bugfix, because we weren't able anymore to increase versions of the cookbook without impacting newly-build machines.
We are considering using the Policyfile system, but first we have to upgrade Chef without breaking everything ...